# I made an BSC token, but i dont know how can i change symbol and name

Tags: token, solidity

I made BSC token to use https://vittominacori.github.io/bep20-generator/

and i get this code

but i dont know how can i change name in this code..

I modified certain parts, split it, and modified the directory path. As far as I know, the place related to name and symbol was modified and compiled, but name and symbol are registered in an unconfirmed state.

this is all code of bsc token

```
    /**
     *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2021-05-01
    */

    /**
     *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2021-03-28
    */

    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    // File: @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    /*
     * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
     * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
     * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
     * manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and
     * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
     * is concerned).
     *
     * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
     */
    abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see 
    https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
    }

    // File: @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    /**
     * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
     * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
     * specific functions.
     *
     * By default, the owner account will be the one that deploys the contract. This
     * can later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
     *
     * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
     * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
     * the owner.
     */
    abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor () {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions anymore. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
    }

    // File: contracts/token/BEP20/lib/IBEP20.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    /**
     * @dev Interface of the BEP standard.
     */
    interface IBEP20 {

    /**
     * @dev Returns the token name.
     */
    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the token symbol.
     */
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the token decimals.
     */
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the token owner.
     */
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
     */
    function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    }

    // File: contracts/token/BEP20/lib/BEP20.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;



    /**
     * @dev Implementation of the {IBEP20} interface.
     *
     * This implementation is agnostic to the way tokens are created. This means
     * that a supply mechanism has to be added in a derived contract using {_mint}.
     *
     * We have followed general OpenZeppelin guidelines: functions revert instead
     * of returning `false` on failure. This behavior is nonetheless conventional
     * and does not conflict with the expectations of BEP20 applications.
     *
     * Additionally, an {Approval} event is emitted on calls to {transferFrom}.
     * This allows applications to reconstruct the allowance for all accounts just
     * by listening to said events. Other implementations of the EIP may not emit
     * these events, as it isn't required by the specification.
     *
     * Finally, the non-standard {decreaseAllowance} and {increaseAllowance}
     * functions have been added to mitigate the well-known issues around setting
     * allowances. See {IBEP20-approve}.
     */
    contract BEP20 is Ownable, IBEP20 {
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;

    /**
     * @dev Sets the values for {name} and {symbol}, initializes {decimals} with
     * a default value of 18.
     *
     * To select a different value for {decimals}, use {_setupDecimals}.
     *
     * All three of these values are immutable: they can only be set once during
     * construction.
     */
    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _decimals = 18;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the name of the token.
     */
    function name() public view override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the symbol of the token, usually a shorter version of the
     * name.
     */
    function symbol() public view override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the number of decimals used to get its user representation.
     * For example, if `decimals` equals `2`, a balance of `505` tokens should
     * be displayed to a user as `5,05` (`505 / 10 ** 2`).
     *
     * Tokens usually opt for a value of 18, imitating the relationship between
     * Ether and Wei. This is the value {BEP20} uses, unless {_setupDecimals} is
     * called.
     *
     * NOTE: This information is only used for _display_ purposes: it in
     * no way affects any of the arithmetic of the contract, including
     * {IBEP20-balanceOf} and {IBEP20-transfer}.
     */
    function decimals() public view override returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-totalSupply}.
     */
    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-balanceOf}.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-getOwner}.
     */
    function getOwner() public view override returns (address) {
        return owner();
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-transfer}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - the caller must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-transferFrom}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance. This is not
     * required by the EIP. See the note at the beginning of {BEP20}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `sender` and `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     * - the caller must have allowance for ``sender``'s tokens of at least
     * `amount`.
     */
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-approve}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IBEP20-allowance}.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    /**
     * @dev Atomically increases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
     *
     * This is an alternative to {approve} that can be used as a mitigation for
     * problems described in {IBEP20-approve}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] + addedValue);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Atomically decreases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
     *
     * This is an alternative to {approve} that can be used as a mitigation for
     * problems described in {IBEP20-approve}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` must have allowance for the caller of at least
     * `subtractedValue`.
     */
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero");
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Moves tokens `amount` from `sender` to `recipient`.
     *
     * This is internal function is equivalent to {transfer}, and can be used to
     * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `sender` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
        _balances[recipient] += amount;

        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    /** @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
     * the total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "BEP20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply += amount;
        _balances[account] += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
     * total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "BEP20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
        require(accountBalance >= amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[account] = accountBalance - amount;
        _totalSupply -= amount;

        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner` s tokens.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
     * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `owner` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets {decimals} to a value other than the default one of 18.
     *
     * WARNING: This function should only be called from the constructor. Most
     * applications that interact with token contracts will not expect
     * {decimals} to ever change, and may work incorrectly if it does.
     */
    function _setupDecimals(uint8 decimals_) internal {
        _decimals = decimals_;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Hook that is called before any transfer of tokens. This includes
     * minting and burning.
     *
     * Calling conditions:
     *
     * - when `from` and `to` are both non-zero, `amount` of ``from``'s tokens
     * will be to transferred to `to`.
     * - when `from` is zero, `amount` tokens will be minted for `to`.
     * - when `to` is zero, `amount` of ``from``'s tokens will be burned.
     * - `from` and `to` are never both zero.
     *
     * To learn more about hooks, head to xref:ROOT:extending-contracts.adoc#using-hooks[Using Hooks].
     */
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }
    }

    // File: contracts/token/BEP20/lib/BEP20Capped.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


    /**
     * @dev Extension of {BEP20} that adds a cap to the supply of tokens.
     */
    abstract contract BEP20Capped is BEP20 {
    uint256 private _cap;

    /**
     * @dev Sets the value of the `cap`. This value is immutable, it can only be
     * set once during construction.
     */
    constructor (uint256 cap_) {
        require(cap_ > 0, "BEP20Capped: cap is 0");
        _cap = cap_;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the cap on the token's total supply.
     */
    function cap() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _cap;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {BEP20-_mint}.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
        require(totalSupply() + amount <= cap(), "BEP20Capped: cap exceeded");
        super._mint(account, amount);
    }
    }

    // File: contracts/token/BEP20/lib/BEP20Mintable.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


    /**
     * @title BEP20Mintable
     * @dev Implementation of the BEP20Mintable. Extension of {BEP20} that adds a minting behaviour.
     */
    abstract contract BEP20Mintable is BEP20 {

    // indicates if minting is finished
    bool private _mintingFinished = false;

    /**
     * @dev Emitted during finish minting
     */
    event MintFinished();

    /**
     * @dev Tokens can be minted only before minting finished.
     */
    modifier canMint() {
        require(!_mintingFinished, "BEP20Mintable: minting is finished");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @return if minting is finished or not.
     */
    function mintingFinished() public view returns (bool) {
        return _mintingFinished;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to mint tokens.
     *
     * WARNING: it allows everyone to mint new tokens. Access controls MUST be defined in derived 
    contracts.
     *
     * @param account The address that will receive the minted tokens
     * @param amount The amount of tokens to mint
     */
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public canMint {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
     *
     * WARNING: it allows everyone to finish minting. Access controls MUST be defined in derived 
    contracts.
     */
    function finishMinting() public canMint {
        _finishMinting();
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
     */
    function _finishMinting() internal virtual {
        _mintingFinished = true;

        emit MintFinished();
    }
    }

    // File: contracts/token/BEP20/lib/BEP20Burnable.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


    /**
     * @dev Extension of {BEP20} that allows token holders to destroy both their own
     * tokens and those that they have an allowance for, in a way that can be
     * recognized off-chain (via event analysis).
     */
    abstract contract BEP20Burnable is BEP20 {
    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from the caller.
     *
     * See {BEP20-_burn}.
     */
    function burn(uint256 amount) public virtual {
        _burn(_msgSender(), amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, deducting from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * See {BEP20-_burn} and {BEP20-allowance}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - the caller must have allowance for ``accounts``'s tokens of at least
     * `amount`.
     */
    function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) public virtual {
      uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(account, _msgSender());
      require(currentAllowance >= amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds allowance");
      _approve(account, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
      _burn(account, amount);
    }
    }

    // File: contracts/service/ServicePayer.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    interface IPayable {
    function pay(string memory serviceName) external payable;
    }

    /**
     * @title ServicePayer
     * @dev Implementation of the ServicePayer
     */
    abstract contract ServicePayer {

    constructor (address payable receiver, string memory serviceName) payable {
        IPayable(receiver).pay{value: msg.value}(serviceName);
    }
    }

    // File: contracts/token/BEP20/CommonBEP20.sol



    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;






    /**
     * @title CommonBEP20
     * @dev Implementation of the CommonBEP20
     */
    contract CommonBEP20 is BEP20Capped, BEP20Mintable, BEP20Burnable, ServicePayer {

    constructor (
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint8 decimals,
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 initialBalance,
        address payable feeReceiver
    )
        BEP20(name, symbol)
        BEP20Capped(cap)
        ServicePayer(feeReceiver, "CommonBEP20")
        payable
    {
        _setupDecimals(decimals);
        _mint(_msgSender(), initialBalance);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to mint tokens.
     *
     * NOTE: restricting access to owner only. See {BEP20Mintable-mint}.
     *
     * @param account The address that will receive the minted tokens
     * @param amount The amount of tokens to mint
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal override(BEP20, BEP20Capped) onlyOwner {
        super._mint(account, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
     *
     * NOTE: restricting access to owner only. See {BEP20Mintable-finishMinting}.
     */
    function _finishMinting() internal override onlyOwner {
        super._finishMinting();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `name` and `symbol` (along with other defined parameters) to the `CommonBEP20` constructor when you're deploying the contract.

If the contract was already deployed, there's no way to change these params and you'll need to deploy a new contract with new values.

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "name and symbol are registered in an unconfirmed state", but if you mean that the deployment transaction (setting up the `name` and `symbol` values) has not been mined, you can try to overrun this transaction by sending a tx with the same nonce, from the same address, just with higher gas price - this time containing different values in the `data` field that will reflect the changed `name` and `symbol` values.